# UNION in Oracle Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, syntax-error

Im trying to do the most basic of stored procs in Oracle. I am simply trying to return 2 queries joined by a union... code is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETATMCONTRACTSBYMANAGERID  (
   MANAGERID IN NUMBER
) AS 
BEGIN
  select t.ID, t."NUMBER", t.TITLE, t.NOTES, t.CONTRACT_TYPE_ID as CONTRACT_TYPE_ID,   t.CONTRACT_STATUS_ID as CONTRACT_STATUS_ID, t.TASK_NUMBER as TASK_NUMBER, c.CONSULTANT_ID,t.TASK_MANAGER_ID, t.IS_COMPREHENSIVE, t."NUMBER", TO_DATE(SUBSTR(t."NUMBER", 8, 2), 'rr')  as val, SUBSTR(t."NUMBER", 11, 3) as val2, t.REF_ID from CONTRACT t INNER JOIN CONTRACT c on c.ID = t.REF_ID
  where t.TASK_MANAGER_ID = MANAGERID;
  UNION 
  select t.ID, t."NUMBER", t.TITLE, t.NOTES, t.CONTRACT_TYPE_ID as CONTRACT_TYPE_ID, t.CONTRACT_STATUS_ID as CONTRACT_STATUS_ID, t.TASK_NUMBER as TASK_NUMBER, t.CONSULTANT_ID, t.TASK_MANAGER_ID, t.IS_COMPREHENSIVE, t."NUMBER", TO_DATE(SUBSTR(t."NUMBER", 8, 2), 'rr')  as val, SUBSTR(t."NUMBER", 11, 3) as val2, t.REF_ID from CONTRACT t
  where t."NUMBER" in (select "NUMBER" from Contract t1 where t1.TASK_MANAGER_ID = MANAGERID)
    and t.TASK_NUMBER = ' '
  order by val desc, val2 desc, TASK_NUMBER asc;
END GETATMCONTRACTSBYMANAGERID;
```

I will be the first to admit I am MUCH more comfortable with SQL Server than I am with oracle but to me it seems like it should work.

The error it returns is:

> Error(7,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UNION" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with          << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge

Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your current problem is the semicolon before the `UNION`. However, once you fix this, you'll have another problem since you do not use the results of your query. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a redundant semicolon (`;`) before the `union` operator - simply remove it:

```
select t.ID, t."NUMBER", t.TITLE, t.NOTES, t.CONTRACT_TYPE_ID as CONTRACT_TYPE_ID,   t.CONTRACT_STATUS_ID as CONTRACT_STATUS_ID, t.TASK_NUMBER as TASK_NUMBER, c.CONSULTANT_ID,t.TASK_MANAGER_ID, t.IS_COMPREHENSIVE, t."NUMBER", TO_DATE(SUBSTR(t."NUMBER", 8, 2), 'rr')  as val, SUBSTR(t."NUMBER", 11, 3) as val2, t.REF_ID from CONTRACT t INNER JOIN CONTRACT c on c.ID = t.REF_ID
  where t.TASK_MANAGER_ID = MANAGERID -- Semicolon removed here
  UNION 
  select t.ID, t."NUMBER", t.TITLE, t.NOTES, t.CONTRACT_TYPE_ID as CONTRACT_TYPE_ID, t.CONTRACT_STATUS_ID as CONTRACT_STATUS_ID, t.TASK_NUMBER as TASK_NUMBER, t.CONSULTANT_ID, t.TASK_MANAGER_ID, t.IS_COMPREHENSIVE, t."NUMBER", TO_DATE(SUBSTR(t."NUMBER", 8, 2), 'rr')  as val, SUBSTR(t."NUMBER", 11, 3) as val2, t.REF_ID from CONTRACT t
  where t."NUMBER" in (select "NUMBER" from Contract t1 where t1.TASK_MANAGER_ID = MANAGERID)
    and t.TASK_NUMBER = ' '
  order by val desc, val2 desc, TASK_NUMBER asc;
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as the semi colon issue, you will need to select INTO a variable to get your code to compile.